# How do I use multiple Pinia stores in Vue options api?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, pinia, vue-options-api

I have a couple of different Pinia stores but, I cant get the page to switch to a different store when the page loads.

This is what i tried:

```
mounted() {
    this.$pinia.use(useMachineService);
}
```

But when I switch to a different page the same store gets used.

Comment: please also share your pinia store

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the fricking problem. The problem was that I forget to give the defineStore a string parameter:

```
export const useUserService = defineStore('useUserService', {
```

It works if you don't use the string but then you wont be able to use multiple stores